# What happens if I accidentally override Apple's private APIs?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say that Apple has an API defined in a private header file:

```
// Can't see this at all
@interface NSThing
- (void)secretMethod;
@end
```

and I have a category:

```
@interface NSThing (Helpers)
- (void)secretMethod;
@end
```

Does this override Apple's implementation and will their other private methods start calling into my implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From ["Avoid Category Method Name Clashes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html):

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method
>   in the original class, or a method in another category on the same
>   class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which
>   method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an
>   issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause
>   problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch classes.

So if you "accidentally" implement a category method with the same name as
an existing method (private or not), the behaviour is **undefined**.

You should therefore prefix your category methods with a prefix that makes
name clashes unlikely.

Comment: It'd also help if Apple prefixed their private selectors with underscores but they don't always do that. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @ide: Very true. There are even private *classes* that are not prefixed with NS, UI or something.